# What are the advantages of using filebeat as shipper?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

Filebeat is used to ship log data into logstash. Logstash read that data at port 5044.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
```

We can directly feed data into logstash.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/tmp/access_log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
```

My question is that why do we need filebeat as a shipper? What are the advantages of using filebeat as shipper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to install Filebeat on every server you need to gather logs and stats from. Each of those Filebeat instances will grab and ship the logs as fast as possible without any processing to a centralized Logstash instance where the bulk of the processing and filtering can take place.

Formerly, Logstash had a [lightweight logstash-forwarder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/migrating-from-logstash-forwarder.html) module which would perform more or less the same work as Filebeat does. Filebeat is the new official and standard way of centralizing logs from all your different hosts.

Comment: So to make shipping faster, we need to use filebeat.

Comment: Yes, the goal of Filebeat is to send the logs as fast as possible away from your server.